# Remote exectution of bat file through Winform

Tags: winforms, remote-access

There are bat files on some servers that we have. I have Winform app that can view directory files and executables on different server. Is there a way that (based on the selected bat file), to be be able to run that bat file on that server from the Winform app.

Comment: You can create a `WCF` service application and host it on server (in iis or in a console application) then from the client, call the service on server and pass the file name that you want the server execute. The service will receive the request and will execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you are thinking. If you run a batch file from your machine (via app or manually) it runs locally on your machine, not on the remote server.

If you can install software, [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) maybe be a good fit. If not, I have a couple of options I can think of.

Alternatives: create an app that runs on the server that knows when to run the batch files (via messaging, database records, etc) or use the Windows Task Scheduler.

The Task Scheduler approach is fairly simple. You could have the batch files set to run every one minute and at the start of the batch file, you do a file check. Your WinForm would create that file and at the end of the batch (if the file existed at the start) it would delete the file that triggers the batch.